# Why is MySQL not saving inserted data?

Tags: mysql, innodb

So I have the following insert statement that I run through MySQL Workbench:

```
INSERT INTO PeakOnlineCount
(time_stamp, LocationId, Count)
values
('2015-03-26', 0, 1)
```

If I run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM PeakOnlineCount
```

straight after in the same tab, I can see the results. If I disconnect, reconnect and run the select query the table seems empty.

If I run the insert statement on one computer and run the select from another, the table is empty.

I'm not using transactions or anything like that. What's going on?

(And yes I know that I'm using `SELECT *`, this is only for the question)

Here's the structure of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `PeakOnlineCount` (
    `time_stamp` date NOT NULL,
    `LocationId` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `Count` int(11) NOT NULL,
    KEY `IX_LocationDate` (`time_stamp`,`LocationId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I'm not using auto-commit and according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commit.html:

> By default, MySQL runs with autocommit mode enabled. This means that as soon as you execute a statement that updates (modifies) a table, MySQL stores the update on disk to make it permanent. The change cannot be rolled back.

I certainly haven't turned off auto-commit.

I have run `SHOW TABLES` and I've copied and pasted the table name from that. Also, I'm running all the queries in the same window so should be connected to the same schema in all queries.

There are no triggers on the table. I try to avoid triggers as much as possible.

Ran `show variables`, `show session variables`, and `show global variables`. All say that autocommit is turned on.

I am using workbench, but I have a colleague using something else (sequel pro on a mac) who runs the insert query and then I've run the select query and got nothing back.

Comment: Please try running the `INSERT ... ; COMMIT;` in you machine, then close the window. And reopen it. Does the row appear?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655824/cant-see-inserted-data-from-mysql-immediately or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742133/why-is-my-jdbc-prepared-statement-update-not-updating-the-database or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318347/why-are-some-mysql-connections-selecting-old-data-the-mysql-database-after-a-del